# OpenERP upgrade modules

Tags: odoo

I use the warehouse module, but when I want to update it, the system updates the purchasing module also.

can someone tell me why this happened even if that module does not depend on purchase module?

I don't think even if I'm not using purchase I should leave it installed? the real problem is I don't want that module in my application, but the system didn't let me remove it !

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I agree with you that stock has no direct dependency on purchase but if you see closely you will find some bridge like, stock > product < purchase, Now point is when you update stock moudle it will update all child account and it's dependency also so stock is updating the product and here  product is also in -u . when you see if some parent are being updated all child will also be marked to be updated, This process is chinning process.
if you have depedeancy like A> B> C  and D>B  if you try to update the module D it will start series of chain like D, B, C, and base and many more child are affecte by this series of chain.

Hope you getting the point here.

Comment: But I don't think even if I'm not using purchase I should leave it installed? the real problem is I don't want that module in my application, but the system didn't let me remove it !

Answer (score 1):

**purchase** depends on **stock**. So, when you update **stock**, **purchase** has to be updated too.